# Simplifying for Nested For Loops with Parallel For Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I need help simplifying this nested parfor and for loops where the vars, mats and arrays are:
Y is 5000 x 147 matrix,
numProperties is 5000, 
PaymentTable is 54000 x 4 matrix, 
boolFlag is 5000 arrays,
LookUpID is 5000 arrays,
numPeriods is 5000 arrays,
PaymentType is 5000 cell arrays

```
Y = cell2mat(Y);
Y = [zeros(numProperties,1) Y(:,5:end) zeros(numProperties,4)];
for idx=1:numProperties;
    maxPeriod=numPeriods(idx)+1;
    parfor jdx=2:maxPeriod;
        for kdx=1:size(PaymentTable);
            if boolFlag(idx)==1 && LookUpID(idx)==PaymentTable(kdx,2) && PaymentTable(kdx,4)~=0 && PaymentTable(kdx,3)==jdx-1 && Y(idx,jdx)==0;
                if PaymentTable(kdx,1)==2 && strcmp(PaymentType(idx),'Slow');
                    NonQuickRepayments(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==2 && strcmp(PaymentType(idx),'Quick');
                    QuickRepayments(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==3;
                    MoneyFlows(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==4;
                    Outstanding(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==5;
                    IntrinsicValue(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==6;
                    OtherValue(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==7;
                    ForexAdjustment(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==8;
                    BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx)=-PaymentTable(kdx,4)+BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==9;
                    BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx)=-PaymentTable(kdx,4)+BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==10;
                    BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx)=-PaymentTable(kdx,4)+BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx);
                elseif PaymentTable(kdx,1)==11;
                    BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx)=-PaymentTable(kdx,4)+BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx);
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to simplify your `for` loops. The code doesn't look like it could be vectorized, and if you have three variables to be enumerated you need three loops.

You could simplify the long `if/elseif` statement though; use `switch` instead. Moreover, cases 8 to 11 do the same thing.

```
        switch PaymentTable(kdx,1)
            case 2
                if strcmp(PaymentType(idx),'Slow');
                    NonQuickRepayments(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                elseif strcmp(PaymentType(idx),'Quick');
                    QuickRepayments(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
                end
            case 3
                MoneyFlows(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
            case 4
                Outstanding(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
            case 5
                IntrinsicValue(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
            case 6
                OtherValue(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
            case 7
                ForexAdjustment(idx,jdx)=PaymentTable(kdx,4);
            case {8, 9, 10, 11}
                BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx)=-PaymentTable(kdx,4)+BalanceToDispose(idx,jdx);
            end
        end
```